# How to make a button in HTML?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid

I'm a beginner and trying to make a website for school project using CSS grid and Flexbox, but I'm having 2 problem and I can't fix it.

First, I can make the header fit the page, as you can see from the picture, the header(red background) is bigger than I expect, I'm hoping the height is same as the pokeball on the top left, but for some reason it's about the half screen size.

Second, I'm not sure how  is the button work, as you can see I have a button called click here and I want when the user click it, the left side menu expend, if the user click again, it goes back. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6KTu.jpg)

For the first one, I did try to add more grid rows and columns to adjust it, but it did not work well.

As for the button, I don't know how it works, so I hope someone can help me.

I just want when the user clicks it, the Menu expand, otherwise it suppose to only show

```
<div>My Favorite Pokemon</div>
```

Here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="Header flex-container">
        <div><img src="img/pokeball.png" alt="Pokemon Ball">Pokemon</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Menu">
        <div>My Favorite Pokemon</div>
        <article>
            <div class="point" onclick="location.href='#Pikachu'"><span class="bc"><u>Pikachu</u></span></div>
            <div class="point" onclick="location.href='#Giratina'"><span class="bc"><u>Giretina</u></span></div>
            <div class="point" onclick="location.href='#Arceus'"><span class="bc"><u>Arceus</u></span></div>
            <div class="point" onclick="location.href='#Snorlax'"><span class="bc"><u>Snorlax</u></span></div>
            <div class="point" onclick="location.href='#Lucario'"><span class="bc"><u>Lucario</u></span></div>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: Why don't you use `<button>`?

Answer (score 0):

For the header, try setting the height attribute to fit-content. If the image is properly scaled, it should become the same height as the image. Otherwise, you can define the height and width values for the image as well to adjust it.

For the button functionality, you will need to implement javascript. Here is a tutorial on how to create a collapsable element https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp